# JS is not pulling data from Forismatic API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

EDIT: I figured out the solution myself but I would like some answer why this worked. I deleted the https:// from the url and it fixed the problem. Not sure why this would be an issue. Maybe that https is more secure?

Here is some of my relevent HTML and Js code it is written on codepen so the headers and libraries aren't directly in the code. Here is the link to the codepen page: https://codepen.io/slicknick/pen/vXVYpg

This is a project to create a random quote generator using the Forismatic API. I am new to API's and Js. I can't seem to be able to get the quotes to display on my page and would like some feedback as to why this might be happening.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered">
        <blockquote>
            <p id="quote-text"></p>
            <footer>
                <a id="author" target="_blank"></a>
            </footer>
        </blockqoute>
        <button type="button" id="getQuote" class="btn btn-secondary">New quote</button>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=%23Quote" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x" id="twitter-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
var author = $('#author');
var text = $('#quote-text');
getQuote(author, text);

$('#getQuote').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    getQuote(author, text);
    $('#twitter-share').removeClass("disabled");
    $('#twitter-share').html("Share with Twitter!");
})
});

var tweetText = "";
$('#twitter-share').click(function() {
if (tweetText.length > 140) {
    tweetText = "";
    $(this).addClass("disabled");
    $(this).html("140 chars exceeded!");
} else {
    $(this).attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" +        tweetText);
}

})

function getQuote(author, text) {

var forismaticURL = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/? method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?"

$.getJSON(forismaticURL, function(data) {

    text.html(data.quoteText);
    if (data.quoteAuthor) {
        author.html(data.quoteAuthor);
        author.attr("href", data.quoteLink);
    } else {
        author.removeAttr("href");
        author.html("<strong>Anonymous</strong>");
    }
    tweetText = data.quoteText + "By -" + data.quoteAuthor;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Forismatic API Documentation

> **API method calls are implemented in the form of HTTP requests to the URL  http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/.**

That's why you are getting Error 404 on HTTPS.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks it does. I am sure I will get a better grasp on things the deeper I get into API.